# Can't write hex bytes through bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a byte array, I need to convert it to hex values and send them through bluetooth. Everything I found is to convert bytes to hex string, but I can't do it because I can write only byte arrays or int.

```
public static byte[][] commandsArray = new byte[5][5];

...
connectedThr.write(ConstantsVariables.commandsArray[i]);

...

public void write(byte[] bytes) {
   try {
      mmOutStream.write(bytes);
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD","Could not write: " + e.toString());
   }
}
```

Everything with sending is ok, I can write simple byte array. Problem is with hex values and how to send them.

UPD:
I tried this code, but I have such logs:

```
09-26 20:39:57.324 26848-26848/shkatovl.btandroid I/TEST: 28
09-26 20:39:57.324 26848-26848/shkatovl.btandroid I/TEST___2: [B@3ae4f930

Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
                    formatter.format("%02x", ConstantsVariables.commandsArray[i][j]);
                    String hex = formatter.toString();
                Log.i("TEST", hex);
                Log.i("TEST___2", hex.getBytes().toString());
```

Comment: `I have a byte array, I need to convert it to hex values and send them through bluetooth.` AND `but I can't do it because I can write only byte arrays or int.` That is contradictory. Your words do not make sense.  But indeed send the byte array directly. Nothing easier than that.

Comment: @greenapps I send it to arduino and it accepts only hex values.

Comment: You mean that you put a hexadecimal representation of the byte values in a string. So you have to send strings. What is the problem with sending strings? You should send String hex because that is the string. You could even send hex.getBytes() as then you could send those bytes if you dont know how to send a string.

Comment: Please show your Arduino code to see what you mean with hex values.

Comment: @greenapps Because OutputStream has methods to write binary data. And if I use `getBytes("UTF-16")` and then try to print it, I have smth like this `[-1, -2, 50, 0, 56, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 54, 0, 52, 0]` for one byte in first condition

Comment: Why are you printing the bytes decimal? Do it hexadecimal as that was were you were talking about. Further you did not show where getBytes() took the bytes from. So i cannot follow you. Please post a decent complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the String class's `getBytes()` method? There are also Similar methods on the Primitive Object Wrappers (`Integer` etc.) if that is what you need.